# Meaning of notation: $\mathrm{Sm}\left(\mathrm{Fe}_{0.8} \mathrm{Co}_{0.2}\right)_{12}$

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, notation, chemical-compounds

I am reading a research paper about magnetic materials based on $\mathrm{SmFe_{12}}$ compounds (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.actamat.2020.05.026). They talk about the material $\mathrm{Sm}\left(\mathrm{Fe}_{0.8} \mathrm{Co}_{0.2}\right)_{12}$ but I do not understand that notation. Can someone explain what that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is SmFe$_{12}$ in which 20 % of the iron was replaced by cobalt.